# Incorporating slideshow / carousel into custom tumblr theme

Tags: slideshow, carousel, tumblr, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

Got a very particular problem here:

I've been developing a tumblr-hosted site locally, using the API to pull in posts without having to copy and paste the project into tumblr a million times. I decided I liked the API better and would just use that in production, but now that it's time to deploy I realize that I have to go back to the custom theme, `{block:Posts}` method.

I have the post feeding into a [Cycle2](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2) slideshow, with 3 slides containing 3 posts each for a total of 9 playlists viewable without going back to the archive. This method works perfectly with the api, but is getting messed up in the custom theme. Here's my current code:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    {block:Posts}
    {block:Text}

    <div class="slide-wrapper">
        <div class="post">
            {block:Post1}
            {block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}"><h2>{Title}</h2></a>{/block:Title}
            <div class="blog_item">
                {Body}
            </div>

            {/block:Post1}
        </div>  
        <!--two more posts before end of slide... -->
    </div>

    {/block:Text}
    {/block:Posts}
    </div> <!--end of slide wrapper - 2 more of these before end of slideshow div..
```

I also tried scrapping the post numbers, but still no dice. In tumblr's docs, they say that

> Example: {block:Post5}I'm the fifth post!{/block:Post5} will only be rendered on the fifth post being displayed.

I'm wondering if "being displayed" refers to the html `visibility` of the post, and if so, if that's interfering with the cycle plugin? The results are one ill-formatted post per slide, and then after cycling through 2 blank slides, the next oldest post takes its place. I'll be pleasantly surprised if anybody has ever had a similar problem but I would kill for some advice. [Here's](http://wmcn-dev.tumblr.com/#blog) the development site for reference (and the second carousel is working because it's still hooked up to the api). thanks!!

Comment: I can tell right off the bat why this isn't going to work like you want it to: Post are not numbered by their type. Therefore, with this code, `{block:Post1}` is only going to show up if the first post happens to be a text post. Actually, it's probably confusing the heck out of the rendering engine that you have a numbered post inside of a post type and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the following code is what you'd want to have 3 slideshows with 3 posts each.

Note that in the **Additional Settings** on the **Customize** screen, you'd have to set the post count to **9 per page** in order for this to work properly. I wrapped it in an `Index Page` block, otherwise this is going to look nasty on a `Permalink Page`.

```
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Posts}
    {block:Post1}<div class="cycle-slideshow">{/block:Post1}
    {block:Post4}<div class="cycle-slideshow">{/block:Post4}
    {block:Post7}<div class="cycle-slideshow">{/block:Post7}

    <div class="slide-wrapper">

         {block:Text}
         <div class="post">
           {block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}"><h2>{Title}</h2></a>{/block:Title}
           <div class="blog_item">
               {Body}
           </div>
         </div>  
         {/block:Text}

        {block:Photo}
             ...
        {/block:Photo}

        ...

    </div>

    {block:Post3}</div>{/block:Post3}
    {block:Post6}</div>{/block:Post6}
    {block:Post9}</div>{/block:Post9}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

*However*, if you're wanting 3 slideshows with the post types split between the slideshows, the code would look more like the following.

Note that in this scenario, if you were to have 4 texts posts out of 9, all 4 text posts would end up in the `Text` slideshow. You'd have to use Javascript or CSS to remove or hide the additional posts if you're very strict about your 3.

```
{block:IndexPage}
    <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    {block:Posts}
         {block:Text}
         <div class="slide-wrapper">
         <div class="post">
           {block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}"><h2>{Title}</h2></a>{/block:Title}
           <div class="blog_item">
               {Body}
           </div>
         </div>  
         </div>
         {/block:Text}
    {/block:Posts}
    </div>

    <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    {block:Posts}
         {block:Photo}
         <div class="slide-wrapper">
             ...
         </div>
         {/block:Photo}
    {/block:Posts}
    </div>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

If you need me to clarify anything, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, I only want one slideshow, with three "slides," where each slide contains 3 separate posts. So, slide1 (marked by `div.slide-wrapper` should contain posts 1 2 3, slide1 should have 4 5 6, etc. Every post on this blog is text, so the type doesn't matter as much, but I didn't realize that I needed the type inside the numbers - thanks. Does the structure change to put all the posts within one slideshow other than moving the `{block:Post#}` to contain the `div.slide-wrapper`s?

Comment: So I used a modified version of your suggestion and it appears to be working. However, when I click on a post's permalink nothing shows up in the slideshow at all...any suggestions? Thanks so much.